# How can we GET/POST the request to server with scriptaculous.js or prototype.js

Tags: scriptaculous

How can we GET/POST the request to server with scriptaculous.js or prototype.js.
Please explain with brief example if possible..

Regards,
Akash Jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca use `Ajax.Request` to send Ajax requests to your server (must be on the same domain name). For instance (quoting the doc) :

```
new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
  method: 'get',
  parameters: {company: 'example', limit: 12}
  });
```

And, for POST, replace '`get`' by '`post`' ;-)

See :

- [Introduction to Ajax](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax)
- [`Ajax.Request`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request)

Note that this can be used only to send request to a script on your own domainname, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) implemented in web browsers for security reasons.

If you want to send requests to another domain, you'll have to go through a proxy installed on your own *(so the request seems to be sent to your domain)*.

Scriptaculous is an "effects" framework, to do stuff like animations, drag'n drop, and that kinf of things.

It uses Prototype, but doesn't provide any Ajax-requesting functionnaly : it only uses those of Prototype, when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is.  It's a common usecase and thus very prominent in the documentation for Prototype.

**Introduction to Ajax**
http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax